# R: Recognizing a variable in a string query?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Hello stack overflow R community :)

I am trying to write a loop or alternatively a function that I can apply to a vector of values in a table that sends a query to a database. The exact details are possibly not too important as this is more of a general question.
Given that the query is a string like this:

```
query <- '1456-2365 some more text'
```

the number in the beginning is a reference number which is the type of variable I am trying to 'loop' over. As in I have column with similar built values in my table and I'm trying to query all of them. My question is how do I make R recognize my variable within the string?

I have thought of using `str_replace` or similar before re-running the query, are there any better ways of doing this?

Comment: Ususally one one `paste()` or `glue::glue()` together the vector of query strings and loop over that. Don't think we can help more with so little information to go on.

Comment: E.g. with `glue`: `numbers = c("1456-2365", "2", "3", "4")`, `qry = "{numbers} some more text"`, `qry_strings = glue::glue(qry)`.

Answer (score 1):

The details *are* important here. If your number is *always* at the start of the string and *always* followed by a space, you could do:

```
str_extract(df$query, '^\\H*')
#> [1] "1456-2365" "1326-1365" "4567-2885"
```

If your number is not always at the start, but always 4 digits followed by a dash and another four numbers, you could do:

```r
str_extract(df$query, '\\d+-\\d+')
#> [1] "1456-2365" "1326-1365" "4567-2885"
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <- data.frame(query = c('1456-2365 some more text',
                           '1326-1365 blah blah text',
                           '4567-2885 text blah blah'))
```